# Perl IO::Socket::INET обработка сегмента без EOL

Tags: сокет, perl, tcp-ip

Не получается обрабатывать сегмент данных, если данные в нем не завершаются символами 0x0A 0x0D

Сервер выглядит вот так:

```
$server = IO::Socket::INET->new(LocalPort => 7777,
                            TYPE        => SOCK_STREAM,
                            Reuse       => 1,
                            Listen      => SOMAXCONN,
                            KeepAlive   => 1,
                            Timeout     => 10)
or die "Couldn't be a tcp server on port $server_port: $@\n";
while($client = $server->accept()) {
    defined(my $child_pid = fork()) or die "Can't fork new child $!";
    if ($child_pid == 0) {
        close( $server );
    }
    $client->autoflush( 1 );
    while(my $buffer = <$client>) {
        print unpack("H*", $buffer);
    }
}
```

Для наглядности печатается 16-ричное представление данных принятого сегмента. Печать принятых данных срабатывает только если сегмент данных завершается символами 0x0A 0x0D, либо если буфер переполнен, либо если клиент отключился.

Помимо этого нужно иметь возможность печатать все принятые сегменты, даже без 0A 0D в конце.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот здесь:

```
while(my $buffer = <$client>) {
```

Вместо `<>` нужно использовать, например, [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html).

И, кстати,

[As of VERSION 1.18 all IO::Socket objects have autoflush turned on by default](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Socket.html).

Рабочий пример:

**server.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Carp qw/confess/;
use Const::Fast;

const my $CHUNK_MAX   => 1024;
const my $SERVER_PORT => 7777;
const my $SERVER_HOST => '127.0.0.1';

my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new(
    LocalPort => $SERVER_PORT,
    LocalHOST => $SERVER_HOST,
    TYPE      => SOCK_STREAM,
    Reuse     => 1,
    Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
    KeepAlive => 1,
    Timeout   => 10
) or confess "Can not create server on $SERVER_HOST:$SERVER_PORT: $@";

while ( my $client = $server->accept() ) {
    while ( sysread( $client, my $buffer, $CHUNK_MAX ) ) {
        say $buffer. ' => ' . unpack( "H*", $buffer );
    }
}
```

**client.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Carp qw/confess/;
use Const::Fast;

const my $SERVER_PORT => 7777;
const my $SERVER_HOST => '127.0.0.1';

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new("$SERVER_HOST:$SERVER_PORT")
    or confess "Can not connect to server on $SERVER_HOST:$SERVER_PORT: $@";

print $sock 'BADDCAFE';
sleep 10;
print $sock 'DEADBEEF';
close($sock);
```